# Swift2- NSTimer Crashing

Tags: ios, crash, double, swift2, nstimer

When I tried to make the timer to be dynamic, it crashes.
Added code as follows let me know where im making mistake:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let tTimer = defaults.stringForKey("ThankYouTimer")
let doubleTimerValue:Double = NSString(string: tTimer!).doubleValue
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(doubleTimerValue, target: self, selector: "fireTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not your real code, is it? If it is, what the heck is `tTimer`? If it isn't, delete it and show real code.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: And the exception text.  "Unrecognized selector sent to instance", no doubt...

Comment: @trojanfoe That or `tTimer` is unexpectedly nil

Comment: tTimer it has slider value which is stored in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @trojanfoe if the reason is clear for you, why you din't answer?

Comment: @user3441734 Because the stacktrace is not available and my comment was a guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
import Foundation

class C {
    func f() {
        print("job")
    }
}
let c = C()
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: c, selector: "f", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
// 2015-11-06 09:22:55.261 Untitled Page[28568:1397919] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fd51352d190 of class '__lldb_expr_574.C' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector -[__lldb_expr_574.C f]
```

If you subclass C from NSObject

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
import Foundation

class C: NSObject {
    func f() {
        print("job")
    }
}
let c = C()
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: c, selector: "f", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
// print "job" as expected
```

or define you funcion as @objc

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
import Foundation

class C {
    @objc func f() {
        print("job")
    }
}
let c = C()
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: c, selector: "f", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
// print "job" as expected
```